# Как сделать чтобы GULP прописывал правильные пути к файлам?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, gulp

Gulp собирает html файлы с gulp-file-include, есть один файл head.html где прописан такой путь:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">`

Но в разных файлах нужны разные пути, например:

В первом файле должен быть этот же путь: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">`

Во втором такой: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.min.css">`

А в третьем вот такой: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.min.css">`

То же самое и с JS

Как можно всё это дело автоматизировать ??

gulpfile.js, head.html:
https://codepen.io/porohmaxgame/pen/JjrJbWB?editors=1010

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы свой gulpfile приложили